# How do I detect the currently installed features during a MajorUpgrade using WiX Burn MBA Bundles?

Tags: c#, wix, burn, wix3.7

I'm using WiX 3.7's Burn/Managed Bootstrapper Application features to create a custom MBA-based installer. For each of the packages in my bundle's chain, when performing a MinorUpdate, I can easily detect which of the package features are already installed to ensure I maintain those feature selections during the upgrade by using these events provided in the WiX base class for the bootstrapper: `DetectPackageComplete`, `DetectMsiFeature`, `DetectRelatedBundle`, `DetectRelatedMsiPackage`, `DetectComplete`.

However, **during a MajorUpgrade, I'm only seeing a way to determine which package(s) are installed, but am not seeing how to determine which features are installed, as the DetectMsiFeature event does not fire.**  I tried using the `MigrateFeatures` flag on the product's configuration, but that doesn't seem to work (or I'm not using it right).

**What is the correct way to detect/migrate existing features when performing a MajorUpgrade using a Custom Managed Bootstrapper Application in WiX?**

---

#### Some file snippets:

Note: I can provide a fully working VS Solution with all code if that is helpful.

Bundle.wxs:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
    <Bundle Name="Bootstrapper1"  Version="1.1.0.0" Manufacturer="Knights Who Say Ni" UpgradeCode="e6fbf160-d1d9-4b38-b293-94d60eae876f" Compressed="yes">    
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost" >
          <Payload SourceFile="$(var.ManagedBootstrapperApplication.TargetPath)" />
          <!-- other files here -->
        </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
        <Chain>      
          <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Web" />
          <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.SetupProject1.TargetPath)" EnableFeatureSelection="yes" Vital="yes"  Compressed="yes" />
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Product.wxs:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="SetupProject1" Language="1033" Codepage="1252"
           Version="1.1.0.0" Manufacturer="Knights Who Say Ni" 
           UpgradeCode="5fcd463a-3287-4fdf-bf00-d5d74baeccda">

        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
        <MajorUpgrade AllowSameVersionUpgrades="no" AllowDowngrades="no" MigrateFeatures="yes" DowngradeErrorMessage="Bring me a shrubbery!" />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

        <Feature Id="feature_one" Title="Primary Feature" Level="1">      
          <Component Id="CMP_emptyFile1" Guid="{1740AFA6-A98F-482A-B319-A153AA1BEF10}" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <File Id="file_emptyFile1" Checksum="yes" KeyPath="yes" Source="TextFile1.txt" />
          </Component>      
        </Feature>
        <Feature Id="feature_Two" Title="Optional Feature" Level="2">
          <Component Id="CMP_emptyFile2" Guid="{F0831C98-AF35-4F5E-BE9A-2F5E3ECF893C}" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <File Id="file_emptyFile2" Checksum="yes" KeyPath="yes" Source="TextFile2.txt"  />
          </Component>
        </Feature>    
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

CustomBootstrapper.cs

```
public class CustomBootstrapperApplication : BootstrapperApplication {        
    protected override void Run() {
            DetectPackageComplete += HandlePackageDetected;
            DetectMsiFeature += HandleFeatureDetected;
            DetectRelatedBundle += HandleExistingBundleDetected;
            DetectRelatedMsiPackage += HandleExistingPackageDetected;
            DetectComplete += HandleDetectComplete;
            this.Engine.Detect();
            //blocks here until DetectComplete fires...
    }

    private void HandleExistingPackageDetected(object sender, DetectRelatedMsiPackageEventArgs e) {
        Log(string.Format("Detected Related Package {2} ({1}) at version {3} which is a {0}",
            e.Operation, e.PackageId, e.ProductCode, e.Version));
    }

    private void HandleExistingBundleDetected(object sender, DetectRelatedBundleEventArgs e) {
        Log(string.Format("Detected Related {2} Bundle {0} at version {1} which is a {3}",
            e.ProductCode, e.Version, e.RelationType, e.Operation));
    }

    private void HandleFeatureDetected(object sender, DetectMsiFeatureEventArgs e) {
        Log(string.Format("Feature {0} from Package {1} detected in state {2}",
            e.FeatureId, e.PackageId, e.State));
    }

    private void HandlePackageDetected(object sender, DetectPackageCompleteEventArgs e) {
        Log(string.Format("Package {0} Detected in State {1}",
            e.PackageId, e.State));
    }

    private void HandleDetectComplete(object sender, DetectCompleteEventArgs e)
    { /* release the main thread to continue with work */ }

}
```

Output on upgrade:

Note that the package and two features were both installed at v1.0.0 and detected in state Absent. The Related Package was detected, but no feature details are included.

```
Detected Related Upgrade Bundle {5eff0a3c-4b0d-4fd9-875f-05117c07f373) at version 1.0.0.0 which is a MajorUpgrade
Package NetFx4OWeb Detected in State Present
Detected Related Package {540AE32D-75C0-4BF3-A72D-ADBE97FSFF3E} (SetupProject1.msi) at version 1.0.0.0 which is a MajorUpgrade
Feature feature_one from Package SetupProjectl.msi detected in state Absent
Feature feature_Two from Package SetupProjecti .msi detected in state Absent
Package SetupProject1.msi Detected in State Absent
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DetectMsiFeature` is telling you the state of features for the new package; it's not installed, so neither are the features. `DetectRelatedMsiPackage` gives you the data you need to query the feature states of the installed version using the (native) MSI API functions `MsiEnumFeatures` and `MsiGetFeatureState`/`MsiGetFeatureUsage`.

Comment: Thanks Bob!  Since the WiX SDK provides some managed wrappers to gather that data, and I'd prefer to let someone else (ie: you guys on the WiX team) handle the native API marshaling, I added a separate answer detailing that route.  Marking yours as the formal answer, since you lead me down the path ;)

Comment: I rarely use DTF so I didn't know what the DTF equivalents were named. :)

Answer (score 17):

I'm marking [Bob Arnson's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17556225/682840) as the answer, since it gave me what I needed to push this along, but for others who come across this post, I thought I'd give a little more detail about how you can gather the feature states using the WiX-provided `ProductInstallation` class (found in the Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll assembly, which is in the WiX SDK), thus removing the need to make your own direct calls to native MSI API.

Here's an example of a method that could be registered to the `DetectRelatedMsiPackage` event.  Note that you'll need to store off the information you gather so that you can set the appropriate states during the Plan phase.

```
private void DetectRelatedMsiPackageHandler(object sender, DetectRelatedMsiPackageEventArgs e)
{
    var existingPackageProductCode = e.ProductCode;
    var actionToBeAppliedToExistingPackage = e.Operation;
    var existingPackageId = e.PackageId;
    var existingPackageVersion = e.Version;

    Log(string.Format("Detected existing related package {0} (product: {1}) at version {2}, which will be {3}",
                      existingPackageId, existingPackageProductCode, existingPackageVersion,
                      actionToBeAppliedToExistingPackage));

    if (actionToBeAppliedToExistingPackage == RelatedOperation.MajorUpgrade)
    {

        //requires reference to WiX Toolset\SDK\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll
        var installedPackage = new Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.ProductInstallation(existingPackageProductCode);
        if (!installedPackage.IsInstalled) {
            Log(string.Format("Migrating Package {0}, which is not installed, so marking it and it's features as Absent", existingPackageId));
            //TODO: add logic to store state so that during Plan phase can set package with package with product code = existingPackageProductCode to PackageState.Absent
        } else {
            Log(string.Format("Migrating features for MajorUpgrade of Package {0}", existingPackageId));

            foreach (var currentInstallFeature in installedPackage.Features) {                        
                if (currentInstallFeature.State == InstallState.Local) {
                    Log(string.Format("Migrating feature {1} of Package {0} - marking as Present", existingPackageId, currentInstallFeature.FeatureName));
                    //TODO: add logic to store state so that during Plan phase can set package and feature states based on this info
                } else {
                    Log(string.Format("Migrating feature {1} of Package {0} - marking as Absent", existingPackageId, currentInstallFeature.FeatureName));
                    //TODO: add logic to store state so that during Plan phase can set package and feature states based on this info
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I struggled with this for a long time before realizing that you need to include `Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll` as a payload in the bundle. Before I added that, I wasn't even getting the DetectRelatedMsi callbacks, and attempting to call a method in that dll manually resulted in the thread seemingly dying without even an exception being thrown.

Comment: @DaveAndersen Thanks a lot for the additional information. You saved me :)