# How to prevent wix custom bootstrapper Uninstallation UI from showing in the upgrade process

Tags: wix, upgrade, burn

I have a custom bootstrapper application installer which has been worked well with the normal features such as install, uninstall and so on. But now I need to add a upgrade feature for the installer exactly for the bundle, but it always shows the installation UI or uninstallation UI during the installation process of newer bundle installer. I know the old version should be removed during this process but I expect the previous version is removed before the newer version installed and the uninstallation process should be in silence mode.

I am new be with Wix, but I have read lots of articles in StackOverflow, and tried most of the related solutions. Such as the following links:

[How do I detect the currently installed features during a MajorUpgrade using WiX Burn MBA Bundles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552989/how-do-i-detect-the-currently-installed-features-during-a-majorupgrade-using-wix/17556225#17556225)

[How to perform Wix Upgrade with custom bootstrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50347930/how-to-perform-wix-upgrade-with-custom-bootstrapper)

[Wix doesn't remove previous version of burn exe during major upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707985/wix-doesnt-remove-previous-version-of-burn-exe-during-major-upgrade)

[WiX burn Upgrade shows uninstall UI at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117285/wix-burn-upgrade-shows-uninstall-ui-at-the-end#new-answer)

Unfortunately None of them work for me. I don't know the call stacks of the burn engine well, so I post my code to [here](https://github.com/biemowo1985/SOF)!

In my code, I have tried the following solutions:

```
private void DetectComplete(object sender, DetectCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    if (LaunchAction.Uninstall == WixBA.Model.Command.Action)
    {
    WixBA.Model.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "Invoking automatic plan for uninstall");
    WixBA.Plan(LaunchAction.Uninstall);
    }
}


private void BootstrapperApplication_ApplyComplete(object sender, ApplyCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.model.BootstrapperApplication.Command.Action == LaunchAction.Uninstall && isRelatedBundlePresent) // this will be called in case of Upgrade of the bundle
    {
            CustomBootstrapperApplication.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me to review my code, that would be appreciate. When you have downloaded my code, please change the MsiVersion parameter with a version number and change the ProjectRootDir paramter to be your local path of solution file in the "ccnetcall-build-language-package.bat" file in "Build" folder, and then create the different versions of the installers by launching the bat file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The `BootstrapperApplication.Command` struct contains the `display` field that your BA should respect when deciding to display UI (or not).

During the upgrade of the old version the value should be `Display.Embedded` or `Display.None` (I forget which off the top of my head).

Comment: Thank you very much for reply me so quick, Master. Actually I could get the "display" field in the log, I remember it is Display.Embedded when upgrading. But it is a read only field, I could not control it display the UI or not. On another word, I dont know how to control the UI, when it should display and when it should be hide.

Comment: `Display` is a read-only field. *Your* code should look at that field and choose not to display UI.

Comment: Sorry, I am a little puzzled. I know my code should choose not to display UI according to the Display field, but I dont know how to implement it. Is there any related tutorial or sample code for it? I am really a new be with wix, so please be my director. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I thought it should have taken some effect on not displaying UI after I use the following code:
1. WixBA.Plan(LaunchAction.Uninstall);
2. CustomBootstrapperApplication.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

but it does not work for me.